# Issue to show data from relational database tables in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a newbie in ruby on rails it's also my first ruby application.

I want to show data from two tables these are

**applied_jobs table: it contains the below columns:**

> applied_jobs_id  |  jobseeker_id  |  expected_salary

**jobseekers table: it contains the below columns:**

> jobseeker_id  |  year_of_experience  |  name

**My view file codes:**

```
 <tbody>
    <% @applicants_view.each do | applicants | %>
      <tr>
        <td><%=  applicants.jobseeker.name%></td>
        <td><%=applicants.jobseeker.year_of_experience %></td>
        <td><%= applicants.expected_salary %></td>
       </tr>
     <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

**My controller codes:**

```
def applicantsList

   @applicants_view = AppliedJob.paginate(page: params[:page],
```

:per_page => 4).order('applied_jobs_id DESC')

```
end
```

**My applied_job model codes:**

```
class AppliedJob < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :jobseeker
end
```

**My jobseeker model codes:**

```
class Jobseeker < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_one :applied_job

end
```

When I try to show data it's showing the below error

```
 C:/wamp/www/hire_us/app/views/applicants_list/applicantsList.html.erb
   where line #51 raised:

  undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

  Rails.root: C:/wamp/www/hire_us
  Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

  app/views/applicants_list/applicantsList.html.erb:51:in `block in
 _app_views_applicants_list_applicants_ist_html_erb___1439381291_141337560'

  app/views/applicants_list/applicantsList.html.erb:49:in
    '_app_views_applicants_list_applicants_ist_html_erb___1439381291_141337560'
```

Someone can help me, please to identify where the bug?

Comment: That means that particular appliedjob record has no associated jobseeker to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid the error by adding

```
<% @applicants_view.each do | applicants | %>
   <% next unless applicants.jobseeker %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

or

```
<% @applicants_view.each do | applicants | %>
   <% applicants.jobseeker.try(:name) %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: At first, thanks for answer, but my issue is still @Ho Man

Comment: does the wamp stack automatically restart the server / reload the files?

Comment: didn't restart, but reloaded

Comment: applicants.jobseeker.try(:name). if it still fails on the same error, same line, its not reloading :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101658/discussion-between-mukto-mona-and-ho-man).